# Image placeholder in firefox

Tags: firefox

Sometimes I use a mobile connection when I travel; if I connect in an area which is not covered really well by mobile networks, I run into issues.

I tried to disable the loading of images from the preference panel. The problem is that Firefox does not load images, but there is no placeholder, and the layout of the web page can change.

Is there a way to enable placeholders for the images?

Comment: For me in FF 9 it is keeping a placeholder and is showing just the background instead, so just updating your FF to the newest version might help.

Comment: I'm using FF 9. Don't see anything in the place of the image.

Comment: could you make a screen and a link to the site? It's working for me.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/213/83770189.png/

Comment: Isn't that the way you want it? It looks just the same but without pictures.

Comment: nope, i would like to see a placeholder because some images has functions like voting up and down etc...Firefox just shows "alt" attribute if present in the image tag.

Comment: ah ok, now I get what you want.

Comment: did you search for addons on addons.mozilla.org?

Comment: Also I suggest you to use User Agent String add-on. So use Iphone 3.0 UAS to view pages as they are displayed on Iphone. It does not work with all pages, but only the ones designed for mobile devices. Well, for Facebook and other social networking pages, it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no practical way to solve this. The cause of the problem is that some images do not have their dimension information set in HTML so the image file must be downloaded and decoded to actually draw the placeholder. When images are disabled, the browser cannot assume anything but that the size is 0x0.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. Tnx.